matlab argument validation varargin
I have a function in Matlab that I would like to provide an optional argument to. However I am using argument validation and the Matlab documentation suggests to avoid using varargin in combination with argument validation. To be consistent with the rest of my functions, I want to use argument validation here so is there a recommended alternative to varargin that allows optional arguments to be passed to the function when argument validation is used?
Thanks

varargin is not useful for optional arguments, you should use it only to allow arbitrary and unlimited input arguments. The documentation pages next to the one you link show how to do optional inputs and name-value pairs (ie named arguments).

FWIW inputParser is a little older but may also be helpful
